# Is MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1 support thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am using g++ --version  "g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0"
While running this program getting 'thread' was not declared in this scope error even after included thread header file.

.\DemoThread.cpp:17:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
thread testThread(funThread, 5);
^~~~~~
.\DemoThread.cpp:19:5: error: 'testThread' was not declared in this scope
testThread.join();

Code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

void funThread(int num) {
   for(int i =0; i< num; i++) {
        cout<< "I am in thread" << endl; 
   }

}



int main() {

    thread testThread(funThread, 5);
    testThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling using below command :
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 .\DemoThread.cpp -o Demothread

Comment: Some MinGW distributions just don't support threading. You might have one of them. [Here's a link to installation instructions for a much more up-to-date compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) that does (and has a package manager with an impressive ecosystem of support libraries and tools).

Comment: try add ```-lpthread``` or ```-pthread``` to compile options